# Pretty print XML in Java like Eclipse does

Tags: java, xml, indentation

Given the following XML structure:

```
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element root = document.createElement("root");
    Element child = document.createElement("child");
    root.appendChild(child);
```

And the following transformer with the specified output properties:

```
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(root), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

I get this expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <child/>
</root>
```

Which output properties do I need to produce the following output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child />
</root>
```

I need something to get a line break after the xml header and a whitespace before the close of empty tags. (like formatting in Eclipse)

My transformer is the default `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get your expected result by adding

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

and having a standalone document. See [section 16 of the XSL Transformations (XSLT) W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output).

Comment: Cool! I thought, this would only add the `standalone="yes"` to the xml header.

Comment: Hm, but this does not add the whitespace before the close of empty tags.